# Problems with connecting to TCP server

Tags: windows, firewall, tcp

I have two PCs in the same LAN: "A1" and "A2". There is another PC in a different LAN: "B". A TCP server is listening on machine "B", port 80. From machine "A1", I can connect successfully to machine "B". If I try to connect from machine "A2", I can see three outgoing TCP-SYN packets, but no response. The SYNs don't reach machine "B".

Windows firewall is turned off on machine "A2". If I start the TCP server on machine "A1", I'm able to connect to it from machine "A2".

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: check the network settings on a1 and a2 whats different?  probably subnet mask in this case.

Comment: IP address of "A1" is x.y.z.245, IP address of "A2" is x.y.z.238, subnet mask is the same: 255.255.255.0, default gateway is the same too: x.y.z.200 (the value of x, y, and z is not important)

Comment: What about the firewall on machine A2 for outgoing connections?
What's doing the routing / NAT'ing between the two LANs?

Comment: oh btw thanks for telling us that (the value of x, y, and z is not important)...

Comment: @tonyroth Sorry...

Comment: @Aceth Oops, I changed notation when writing the question but forgot to change it in the second paragraph :( The Windows firewall on "A2" is turned off. There are multiple firewalls and routers between the two LANs, unfortunately I don't know the architecture in detail.

Comment: "(the value of x, y, and z is not important)" - It is important if those values put the hosts in different subnets.

Comment: @kol no problem was just kinda funny.  Having multiple firewalls and routers does complicated things, can you ping between a1 and b?

Comment: and in this case he was right x,y and z were not important.

Comment: @tonyroth Unfortunately I cannot use ping and tracert. At our company, ICMP traffic is not allowed to pass through intranet firewalls (AFAIK, ICMP is considered a security threat).

Comment: Once again you don't have to tell me about ICMP being a security risk. Passing ping packets within an intranet is not considered much of a security risk,  allowing pings from the internet would be.

Comment: @tonyroth Sorry again... I'm a programmer, not a systems engineer. What's worse, I don't speak/write English well enough. So I'm talking this way because I'm always afraid of being misunderstood... Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: Why not get the company IT to look at it (People who manages the firewalls etc)?

Comment: @kol you seem to write better then most english speaking people! Ok do a route print on a1 and a2 is there a difference?

Comment: @Aceth It turned out that a colleague of mine gave wrong parameters to the IT guys... Pls check out my answer.

Comment: @tonyroth Pls see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could figure out the problem: only part of the IP range of subnet "A" (the part which contained the address of "A1", but not that of "A2") has been allowed to connect to subnet "B".

I greatly appreciate all the help I got in the comments!